# Android - Shape background hides border

Tags: android

I have a parent `LinearLayout` called ContainerLayout where I put 2 other `LinearLayouts` inside of it. The parent LinearLayout has rounded corners, so logically it has to sort of clip anything showing outside the rounded corners right ? Well, Android has another theory...

[image]

The ContainerLayout should have an **outside** border, not an *inner* one.
I wanna be able to hide any overflowing stuff outside of the ContainerLayout, the same we do in CSS if any of you are familiar with `overflow: hidden`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add paddings to your ContainerLayout. In this case try 6 dp.

Comment: This is gonna push the gradient inside leaving gaps